# NullPointerException при работе с массивом классов Java

Tags: java

У меня есть массив класса VKUser. Пользователь моей программы должен вводить данные о пользователях, после чего они отправляются в класс через сеттеры, однако происходит ошибка.

Ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at nikitakapl.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:75)

```
class VKUser {
    private int UserID;
    private String UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserCity;

    void set_UserID(int New_UserID) {
        UserID = New_UserID;
    }
    void set_UserName(String New_UserFirstName, String New_UserLastName) {
        UserFirstName = New_UserFirstName;
        UserLastName = New_UserLastName;
    }
    void set_UserCity(String New_UserCity) {
        UserCity = New_UserCity;
    }
}
```

/-/

```
public  class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Введите кол-во новых учеников: ");
    int UserCount = in.nextInt();

    VKUser [] VKUser_Array = new VKUser[UserCount];

    for (int UserIndex = 0; UserIndex < UserCount; UserIndex ++) {

        boolean isTrue = false;

        do {

            System.out.println("\nВведите UserID: ");
            int UserID = in.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Введите FirstUserName: ");
            String UserFirstName = in.next();
            System.out.println("Введите LastUserName: ");
            String UserLastName = in.next();

            System.out.println("Введите UserCity: ");
            String UserCity = in.next();

            System.out.printf("\nПроверьте правильность введенных вами данных: \n\n" +
                              "UseID: %d\n" +
                              "UserFirstName: %s\n" +
                              "UserLastName: %s\n" +
                              "UserCity: %s\n\n", UserID, UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserCity);

            System.out.println("Введите 1, если введенные вами данные верны или 0, если нет");

            if (in.nextInt() == 1) {
                isTrue = true;

                // ВОТ С ЭТОГО МОМЕНТА ПРОИСХОДИТ ОШИБКА
                VKUser_Array[UserIndex].set_UserID(UserID);
                VKUser_Array[UserIndex].set_UserName(UserFirstName, UserLastName);
                VKUser_Array[UserIndex].set_UserCity(UserCity);
            }

        } while (!isTrue);
    }
```

Comment: Это точно не c#? :D Переменные называйте с маленького регистра, т.к. верхний регистр это названия, например, классов. А по поводу ошибки, вот вы создали массив на указанное количество элементов, но там нет элементов, только `null`, т.к. элементы еще нужно создать через оператор `new`. Открывайте учебник по java и там на первых главах об этом расскажут

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
VKUser user = new VKUser();
user.set_UserID(UserID);
user.set_UserName(UserFirstName, UserLastName);
user.set_UserCity(UserCity);

VKUser_Array[UserIndex] = user;
```

добавьте это в то место, где у вас коммент об ошибке вместо:

```
VKUser_Array[UserIndex].set_UserID(UserID);
VKUser_Array[UserIndex].set_UserName(UserFirstName, UserLastName);
VKUser_Array[UserIndex].set_UserCity(UserCity);
```